# dispatching event from a controller called trough ajax?

Tags: magento, events, controllers, observers

I am making an ajax call to an action from a controller, where after all the code logic executes, i am dispatching an event.
Unfortunately i can't seem to catch this  event with an observer.

I am using the standard dispatch event from controller, add it in my modules config.xml and adding the functionality in my modules observer.php

Has anyone else tried this scenario with success?

Comment: Sounds correct for me. Are there any error logs?

Answer (score 1):

problem solved guys...i had a small error, that's why it was not functioning...
However, for anyone interested, the event is catched just in the same way as it would without ajax call